# Android Studio activity passing data

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activities - login activity, main page activity, profile activity. The login activity will call main page activity and main page activity will call profile activity. How can I pass the data from login activity to profile activity? Is it must pass the data from login activity to main page activity first then pass to profile activity from main page activity? Or is there any other way to pass the data? Thanks!

Comment: Either you use `SharedPreference` or make the declare value which you want to pass as `Static` for global use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that... or you could store the data in a persistent storage and read back whenever required.

---

Learn about `SharedPreferences` here - [Saving Key-Value Sets | SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

- Saving data looks like:

  ```
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
  editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
  editor.commit();
  ```
- Retrieving data looks like:

  ```
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
  long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
  ```

---

Learn about `SQLite Database` here - [Saving Data in SQL Databases | SQLite Database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

- Saving data looks like:

  ```
  // Gets the data repository in write mode
  SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

  // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);
  values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE, subtitle);

  // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
  long newRowId = db.insert(FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
  ```
- Retrieving data looks like:

  ```
  SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

  // Filter results WHERE "title" = 'My Title'
  String selection = FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " = ?";
  String[] selectionArgs = { "My Title" };

  // How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
  String sortOrder =
      FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + " DESC";

  Cursor cursor = db.query(
      FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,                     // The table to query
      projection,                               // The columns to return
      selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
      selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
      null,                                     // don't group the rows
      null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
      sortOrder                                 // The sort order
      );

  List itemIds = new ArrayList<>();
  while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    long itemId = cursor.getLong(
        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FeedEntry._ID));
    itemIds.add(itemId);
  }
  cursor.close();
  ```

Comment: but, these activities are in the same application,,, database and SharedPreferences are not needed.. it is good for sharing data between multiple applications..

Answer (score 0):

**There are two methods to pass values between Activities in Android:**

**1. Using intent:**
Example:
In the Login Activity, put the following code inside the OnClickListiner:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("username", usernameVariable);
intent.putExtra("password", passwordVariable);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, on the mainActivity, to receive the values use the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String u = intent.getStringExtra("username");
    String p = intent.getStringExtra("password");
    // note: the arguments should match the same as its in the loginActivity
}
```

**2. Using Static Variables:**
Example:

On the LoginActivity, create two static attributes. Like the following:

```
Public Class LoginActivity{
    public static String username;
    public static String password;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, in the mainActivity class use the following code to get these values:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    String u=LoginActivity.username;
    String p=LoginActivity.password;
}
```

Hope it solved your problem...

Comment: I am using intent to call activity. Login activity is my first activity. I call main activity from login activity then I call profile activity from main activity. For intend method, how to pass the data from login activity to profile activity?

Comment: With the intent, you can attach the value that you want to send from one activity to another one.. look at my code I showed you clearly..

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way that you can use create a singleton class and store the value and use it.

```
public final class ProfileDataModel {

    private static ProfileDataModel instance;
    private String userName;
    private String address;

    private ProfileDataModel() {
    }

    /**
     * Get Instance for Profile
     * @return
     */
    public static ProfileDataModel getInstance() {
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new ProfileDataModel();
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}


// Use cases 
//Set the data

ProfileDataModel.getInstance().setAddress("Data from login response");
ProfileDataModel.getInstance().setUserName("As per request/response");

//Get the data

String address = ProfileDataModel.getInstance().getAddress();
String userName = ProfileDataModel.getInstance().getUserName();
```